# $.post variables not passing to php getting undefined index error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .post

This code almost works, it inserts into the db and it is giving feedback on the page to say it has updated. However I am getting undefined index between lines 5-8 in the insert_message.php and my database is filling with blank entries (except the date).

Apologies for being new to jquery and AJAX. Need some help.

**form**

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='insert_message.php' method='POST' id='contact_form'>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='email'>Email:</label>
                                <input class='form-control' type='email' id='email' name='email' required='required' maxlength='35'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class='form-group'>
                                <label for='subject'>Subject:</label>
                                <input class='form-control' type='text' id='subject' name='subject' required='required' maxlength='35'/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for='message'>Message:</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id='message' required="required"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" name="reciever" id='receiver' value="Admin">
                    <input class='btn btn-primary' id='submit' type='submit' value='submit' >
                </form>
                <span id="result"></span>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#submit").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var message1 = $('message').val();
       var sender1 = $('sender').val();
       var receiver1 = $('receiver').val();
       var subject1 = $('subject').val();

 $.post("insert_message.php", {message:message1, sender:sender1, receiver:receiver1, subject:subject1}, function(info) { $("#result").html(info);
   });

clearInput();
});

$("#contact_form").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
function clearInput() {
    $("#contact_form :input").each( function() {
       $(this).val('');
    });
}
});
        </script>
```

**insert_message.php**

```
    <?php
include("connections/conn.php");

$getsubject = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST["subject1"]);
$getmessage = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST["message1"]);
$getsender = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST["sender1"]);
$getreceiver = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST["receiver1"]);
$date = date("Y-m-d");

$insertmessage = "INSERT INTO messages (id,subject,message,date,sender,receiver) VALUES (NULL,'$getsubject','$getmessage','$date','$getsender','$getreceiver')";
$insert = mysqli_query($conn, $insertmessage) ;
   if($insert){
               echo "Message Sent";
   }else{
       echo "Message did not send";
   }
```

***UPDATE***

attempted alternative way but I still get the undefined index in the inser_message.php

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#submit").click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
           url: "insert_message.php", 
           type: "POST",
           data: $("#contact_form").serialize(),
           success: function(result){
               $("#result").html(result);
           }
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You are sending parameters named `message`, `sender` and `receiver`, and reading `message1`, `sender1` and `receiver1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in both JS and PHP.

1. Adjust typo in input hidden where actually `name="reciever"` instead of `name="receiver"`;
2. In your `$("#submit").click()` function you're trying to selecting elements with an invalid selector (e.g. `$('message').val()` instead of `$("#message").val()`);
3. Adjust `$_POST` keys by removing `1` at end. If you have any doubt, print the whole array `print_r($_POST)`;
4. This is not an error but a suggestion. Since you require `conn.php` to do your job, I would use `require` instead of `include`.

Comment: Thank you. It was the missing $("#-------").val() that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $conn and the 1's from your 'get' block and, for example:

`$getsubject = mysqli_escape_string($_POST["subject"]);
$getmessage = mysqli_escape_string($_POST["message"]);
$getsender = mysqli_escape_string($_POST["sender"]);
$getreceiver = mysqli_escape_string($_POST["receiver"]);`

Comment: Didn't have any affect.

Comment: Add:

print_r($_POST);

to insert_message.php

Comment: printed out 'Array ( )'

Comment: I attempted to use AJAX and it too is giving me the same issue. I have updated my question to show that code.